# How to use "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs" in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How do I make a Bottom Navigation using "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs" I have two screens in my react native appwhich BottomNavigation will be "Home" and "Profile" screen How can I create that?For example in any random screen i can import that BottomNavigateimport { Pressable } from "react-native"component and i BottomNavigation will come also in any random screenfor example in enteremail screen i can do "navigation. navigate('home')" and it will navigate from settings screen to home screencan you please help me to do that?

earlier I was achieving this by using Pressable and Text but it was very slow how can I use "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs" to do that?

App.js:

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName={routeName}>
        <Stack.Screen name="enteremail" component={Email} />
        <Stack.Screen name="settings" component={Settings} />
        <Stack.Screen name="profile" component={Profile} />
        <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}v
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. You're trying to navigate from one screen to another? Why aren't the methods in the react-navigation docs working for you? Pressable and Text aren't slow, at least not by themselves. Some more context on what you've tried and what isn't happening would help a lot

Comment: @Abe here is what i tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76646744/do-you-have-a-screen-named-home-react-navigation-error