# Problem with Nested Navigators in React Native: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload ... was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, nested, react-navigation

I am currently using a bottom Tab navigator with a Stack navigator nested inside of it.

Tabs.tsx:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator>
    // other screens here
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Stack"
      component={StackNavigator}
     />       
   </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

StackNavigator.tsx:

```
const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="First"
        component={First}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Second"
        component={Second}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

This was working fine, but since I wanted to hide the BottomTabNavigator in my "Second" screen I nested the Tab Navigator inside the StackNavigator as it is shown in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/).

Tabs.tsx after changes:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator>
    // other screens here
    <Tab.Screen
      name="First"
      component={First}
     />       
   </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Stack.tsx after changes:

```
const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Tabs"
        component={Tabs}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Second"
        component={Second}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Now I try to call a navigate function in my "First" component:

```
const First = ({ navigation }) => {
return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
  //other elements
  <FAB
        icon="plus"
        style={styles.fab}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Tabs", {screen: "Second"})}
      />
    );
};
```

But I get this error on pressing the button:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Tabs","params":{"screen":"Second"}} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Tabs'?
```

Since I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61185135/react-native-navigation-error-the-action-navigate-with-payload-name-192-168) that other people had problems with conditional rendering, I wanted to mention that I am using an AuthStack too, which is returned when the user is logged out:

AuthStack.tsx:

```
export default function AuthStack() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Sign In" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Sign Up" component={SignUpScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Forgot Password" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

index.tsx:

```
export default function RootNavigation() {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return user ? <Tabs /> : <AuthStack />;
}
```

App.tsx:

```
export default function App() {
  return <RootNavigation />;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I already tried to find a solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61185135/react-native-navigation-error-the-action-navigate-with-payload-name-192-168) but I couldn't find any answer that solved my problem.

Comment: It's hard to say, as you have not shared which component (or its code) is causing the error, but I would assume that the navigator on which you are calling `navigate`  does not have a screen named "Tabs". E.g. if you are calling this within the tabs component itself, or a screen within the tab navigator.

Comment: You should include the component that is causing the errors code/routing. It is hard to say what is wrong when we can't see where the error is being thrown.

Comment: I updated my answer, so you can see from which component I am calling the navigate function, where the error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, Your `<NavigationContainer>` should be at the root level. Your stack needs to look like this:

##### App.js/tsx

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <RootNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
    )

}
```

##### RootNavigator.js/tsx

```
const stack = CreateNativeStackScreenNavigator() // assuming you're using react-native-screens

const RootNavigator = () => {
    const { user } = useAuth()
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            { user ? 
                <Stack.Screen name={'AuthStack'} component={AuthStack} 
                : <Stack.Screen name={'Tabs'} component={Tabs} }
            <Stack.Screen name={'Second'} component={Second}
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Now with this structure, you can navigate to the **'Second'** screen from any child **StackNavigator/TabNavigator/Drawer** inside the **RootNavigator**.

Comment: I tried this too, but it threw the same error...

Comment: I do not see where is your NavigationContainer.

Comment: My NaviagtionContainer is inside my Tabs.tsx file, which is conditionally rendered, based on the users auth status.

Comment: I've edited my answer. If you need more assistance ping me.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer but im a litte bit confused... it makes sense to me to put the NavigationContainer in my app.tsx around the RootNavigator but why do I need another StackNavigator around my AuthStack.tsx and Tabs.tsx? Also the "Second" Screen is a screen inside my StackNavigator.tsx (which is nested inside my Tabs.tsx) so why do I have it outside as single screen here?

Comment: I thought your Second screen needs to hide the bottom tabs. If you need a screen that doesn’t have the bottom tabs, put it on a root level otherwise it can be in the tabs. In react-navigation each screen can be a stack this is how you group or separate screens in different flows.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you have 2 NavigationContainers.

You only need one `NavigationContainer` in the root of your app as it "is responsible for managing your app state and linking your top-level navigator to the app environment" - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/

I believe having a second NavigationContainer within your tabs component is the root of the problem as this is preventing access to the navigation above that level.

Update your `Tabs.tsx` to the following and the error should go away:

```
<Tab.Navigator>
  // other screens here
  <Tab.Screen
    name="First"
    component={First}
  />       
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: The accepted answer solved my problem, but your answer is also helpful since it was the main part of my problem. However it did not work for me, only to remove the two NavigationContainer and put them on a root level.